# How to add key to json file using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, key-value

i have a json file like this:

```
[
  {

    "DisplayName": "Title1",
    "SignInName": null,
    "RoleDefinitionName": "Name1",
    "RoleDefinitionId": "1111",
    "ObjectId": "0111",
    "ObjectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "CanDelegate": false,
    "Description": null,
    "ConditionVersion": null,
    "Condition": null
  },
  {
   
    "DisplayName": "Title2",
    "SignInName": null,
    "RoleDefinitionName": "Name2",
    "RoleDefinitionId": "1111",
    "ObjectId": "02222",
    "ObjectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "CanDelegate": false,
    "Description": null,
    "ConditionVersion": null,
    "Condition": null
  },
  {
    
    "DisplayName": "Title3",
    "SignInName": null,
    "RoleDefinitionName": "Name3",
    "RoleDefinitionId": "33333",
    "ObjectId": "03333",
    "ObjectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "CanDelegate": false,
    "Description": null,
    "ConditionVersion": null,
    "Condition": null
  }
]
```

I need to add a KEY at a start with all this json as a VALUE of that key using powershell script so it would look like this:

```
{
"ManagedIdentity": [
  {

    "DisplayName": "Title1",
    "SignInName": null,
    "RoleDefinitionName": "Name1",
    "RoleDefinitionId": "1111",
    "ObjectId": "0111",
    "ObjectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "CanDelegate": false,
    "Description": null,
    "ConditionVersion": null,
    "Condition": null
  },
  {
   
    "DisplayName": "Title2",
    "SignInName": null,
    "RoleDefinitionName": "Name2",
    "RoleDefinitionId": "1111",
    "ObjectId": "02222",
    "ObjectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "CanDelegate": false,
    "Description": null,
    "ConditionVersion": null,
    "Condition": null
  },
  {
    
    "DisplayName": "Title3",
    "SignInName": null,
    "RoleDefinitionName": "Name3",
    "RoleDefinitionId": "33333",
    "ObjectId": "03333",
    "ObjectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "CanDelegate": false,
    "Description": null,
    "ConditionVersion": null,
    "Condition": null
  }
]
}
```

I should do it inside one script block, and i am not sure how to figure this out. It is a ready json file that i need to append key to.
The script that gets a file is something like this:
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId 02222 | ConvertTo-Json

to this short script using pipes i need to append a solution to append the key to the file.

Comment: `@{ManagedIdentity = @($existingJSON |ConvertFrom-Json)} |ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Thanks! anyway i figured it out using this sample:

`@{ManagedIdentity=Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId 02222} | ConvertTo-Json`